# Provisioning Profiles missing on Apple Developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I recently started seeing a "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" in the debug output of my mobile App. In debugging the issue I went back to Apple Developer Account and I found that none of my Provisioning Profiles are there anymore. It shouldn't have an effect but the account was renewed a few months back. It's very strange and unexpected - has anyone else seen this? Do I need to remove all my old Provisioning profiles in XCode, generate new ones on the Apple Dev Portal and go from there or is there a way to recover the lost Profiles?

Thanks,
Sanjay.

Comment: Did you switch to use automatic code signing in your projects?

Comment: @wottle I have always had automatic code signing. But irrespective how would that explain the Profiles vanishing from the developer account on Apple Portal?

Comment: Well, in the past, if someone tied to a developer account clicked the "fix issues" button, it would sometimes delete profiles it felt were no longer needed. Typically it would delete any manually created ones in favor of ones created automatically by Xcode.  Automatic code signing could do similar things, although I thought Apple said it wouldn't touch your manual certs, profiles, etc.  Do multiple people share this developer account? Could someone have clicked the "Fix Issues" button?

Comment: @wottle I am the only one using this account. No one else has access to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost impossible to tell why the profiles are now gone.  They may have expired and cleaned up.  If you didn't renew in time, it may have revoked your certificate, causing the profiles to be invalid.

I haven't heard of profiles disappearing on their own, only profiles removed because of some developer action.  Either way, at this point, you can simply create some new profiles, download them to your Mac and build as you normally would.  If you haven't already done so, I would delete the old profiles from your Mac before downloading the new one(s).